# Implement "load more" using threads.list() combined with 'q' = older/newer

Tags: gmail-api

On first sign-up I am doing a full sync for the last 50 threads in label with id `INBOX`.

How should I go about implementing a "load more" feature, where the user can say I would like to fetch the next 50 threads. As far as I see there are 2 possible ways to go about it:

1. Cache `nextPageToken` from initial full sync and use that to load next 50 (`maxResults` = 50)
2. Use the `q` parameter with `older` and `newer` - this works well for dates however I could not find if this works for absolute time.

Neither of them works for my use case in which I specifically would like to get the next 50 threads older or all threads newer than this point of time.

I would like to do this because if I fetch threads per label, and in my data model labels and threads have a many-to-many relationship, I will have date gaps in the different labels.

Here is an example: I go into a label that has messages from 2009, I fetch them. They are also in Inbox so if I go there I will see emails from October 2014 and then suddenly September 2009. My solution would be to fetch threads from All Mail newer than the oldest thread whenever I do load more or initial full sync to make sure there are no date gaps. 
Also to save bandwidth, is it possible to include in the request the thread ids I already have, to not be returned in the response?

Comment: Can you clarify why `nextPageToken` with maxResults=50 doesn't work for you? It seems to be that's how you should get 50 older results. To get the newer results, while saving bandwidth, have you considered using `startHistoryId`: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#partial_synchronization ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to overcomplicate things. If you don't do any newer, older or specific sorting the messages are ordered by date desc. For the pages I created a simple array to hold all the page tokens. Quite easy and works well (AngularJS example):

```
/*
 * Get next page
 */
$scope.fetchNextPage = function() {

    if ($scope.nextPageToken) {
        $scope.page++;
        $scope.pageTokenArray[$scope.page] = $scope.nextPageToken;
        $scope.targetPage = $scope.pageTokenArray[$scope.page];

        $scope.fetch(false);

        // As we have a next page, always allow
        // to go back
        $scope.lastBtnDisabled = false;
    }
};

/*
 * Get previous page
 */
$scope.fetchLastPage = function() {
    if ($scope.page > 0) {
        $scope.page--;
        $scope.targetPage = $scope.pageTokenArray[$scope.page];
        $scope.fetch(false);

        // When page is 0 now, disable last page
        // button
        if ($scope.page == 0) {
            $scope.lastBtnDisabled = true;
        } else {
            $scope.lastBtnDisabled = false;
        }
    }
};
```